# Codeigniter Routing Settings for Tank Auth

Tags: codeigniter, routes, tankauth

I'm using Tank-Auth for my application. And the only problem I have is activating and resetting passwords for accounts.

For login, register, logout; I have no problem with this codes;

```
$route['login'] = "/auth/login";
$route['logout'] = "/auth/logout";
$route['register'] = "/auth/register";
```

But for activating accounts and resetting passwords, those codes are not working;

```
$route['activate/:num/:any'] = "/auth/activate/$1/$2";
$route['reset_password/:num/:any'] = "/auth/reset_password/$1/$2";
```

PS: The first segment after 'activate' is 'user id' and second segment is key like this: example.com/activate/2/4784322e48916efec1153c53d25453c7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is changing url segments in the (auth) controller  from this:

```
    $user_id        = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $new_pass_key    = $this->uri->segment(4);
```

to this:

```
    $user_id        = $this->uri->segment(2);
    $new_pass_key    = $this->uri->segment(3);
```

After this change, the routing for activate&reset_password is working with those rules

```
$route['activate/:num/:any'] = "/auth/activate/$1/$2";
$route['reset_password/:num/:any'] = "/auth/reset_password/$1/$2";
```